# Getting element from array of arrays in JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

Using this JSON as an example: http://steamcommunity.com/id/berthiest/inventory/json/730/2/ I'm trying to get a specific element which is in array, in an array of arrays. It also has the same name as other elements in these arrays. This is the PHP code I'm using now.

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/id/berthiest/inventory/json/730/2/');

$json = json_decode($data);

foreach ($json->rgDescriptions as $mydata)
{
    foreach($mydata->tags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->name;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm searching through the arrays in `"tags"` for the `"name"` element. If you look at the JSON and test this code, you'll notice there are numerous `"name"` elements in the arrays of `"tags"`. The only "`name"` element I want is the one in the array which also contains `"category_name":"Quality"`.

I can't choose the array number to get `"name"` from like this:

```
foreach ($json->rgDescriptions as $mydata)
{
    echo $mydata->tags[3]->name;
}
```

Because there are a different amount of arrays in `"tags"`  throughout the JSON.

Example of `"tags"`:

```
"tags":[{"internal_name":"CSGO_Tool_WeaponCase_KeyTag","name":"Key","category":"Type","category_name":"Type"},{"internal_name":"normal","name":"Normal","category":"Quality","category_name":"Category"},{"internal_name":"Rarity_Common","name":"Base Grade","category":"Rarity","color":"b0c3d9","category_name":"Quality"}]
```

I would want the `"name":"Base Grade"` element from the last array because it contains `"category_name":"Quality"` .

So how can I do this?

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with JavaScript? Please include an minimal example of the data in the post. Either way, it seems the solution would be to simply iterate over all `tags` and check whether any of them has `category_name":"Quality"` and only use that one.

Comment: you decoded the json, therefore it's not json anymore. it's just a plain old PHP data structure. just because it came from a json string doesn't make it magically different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a condition like below

```
foreach($mydata->tags as $tag) {
     if(isset($tag->category_name) && $tag->category_name == 'Quality') {
          echo $tag->name;
     }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll accept the answer soon when it allows me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isset` to test the presence of the data to make sure your condition is true before echo-ing your name. Something like...

```
foreach ($json->rgDescriptions as $mydata)
{
    foreach ($mydata->tags as $tag) {
        if (isset($tag->category_name) && $tag->category_name == 'Quality') {
            echo $tag->name;
        }
    }
}
```